# Why doesn't this PXDefault actually set a Default to my unbound PXBool field?

Tags: acumatica

Here's my field...

`#region SessionValidated - unbound
        public new abstract class sessionValidated : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
        protected bool? _SessionValidated;
        [PXBool]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Validated this Session?")]
        public Boolean? SessionValidated
        {
            get { return this._SessionValidated; }
            set { this._SessionValidated = value; }
        }
 #endregion SessionValidated`

So, I'm trying to figure out why, on RowSelected, this field is coming back NULL.  Shouldn't it be false, since I specified that in my PXDefault attribute?

Comment: How is the record with this field inserted into cache? If it comes from user pressing the '+' button in the UI (or similarly through web-services) or if you call the cache.Insert method PXDefaultAttribute should work. Please provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

Look at PXUnboundDefaultAttribute

```
[PXUnboundDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the value (false) will be persisted to the database when the row is persisted.

If you want to see the value upon placement into the cache, you could use the fielddefaulting event to set it.

Comment: also, just noticed that this is an unbound field, so you will never get it persisted. You will need to use the field defaulting or row selected event to populate the value in the record.